# MonacaでiOSアプリがビルドできません

Tags: ios, monaca

Monaca と iOS Dev Center とで証明書をいろいろ発行してみたのですが、この三日くらい iOS アプリの開発版がビルドエラーになります。

APPID をワイルドカードにしたり、 monaca プロジェクトを一から作り直してみたりもしました。
当初の数回はビルドできていました。ログの始めは以下で、すべて同じ内容です。

```sh
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/5(xxx)
Download complete
Running command: php /private/tmp/monaca/54c74b48fd1734b440a735bf/ios/scripts/build_ios.php --path /data/monaca_build_module/3.5 --type &apos;debug&apos;  2&gt;&amp;1
Prepare keychain...

1 key imported.
Unable to delete certificate matching &quot;iPhone Developer: T(xxx) (G(xxx))&quot;
```

なにかの証明書が削除できないというないようでしょうか？

Comment: ビルド種別(デバッグ、アドホック、リリース)は何でしょうか？証明書作成の手順で、参考としているドキュメントはありますか？

Comment: もっとビルドログを見てみないと、これだけでは原因は解らないですね...

Comment: ビルドエラーが発生した旨が表示されている箇所はもっと下の方かと思います。
上記状態では不足が多く分かりません。また、放置されておりますが、解決したのか、しなかったのかが不明です。